# What is the difference between the two definitions

Tags: scala, implicit, context-bound

What's the difference between the two definitions?

`def f[F[_]: Async](...) = ???`

`def f[F[_]](...)(implicit F: Async[F]) = ???`

later I can use `Async[F].async {}` in first case and `F.async {}` in second
But i can't figure out the difference. Thx.

Comment: If you're not at ease with implicit, you may not use lib like cats effect

Answer (score 1):

I would say, it is just a matter of personal preference.

One is a syntactic sugar to other, You can go with any one of them and achieve same thing.

Note that, you are able to use this `Async[F].async {}` just because someone already defined `apply` method which looks similar to your second option.

If that was not the case, then you had to write it like `implicitly[Async[F]].async {}`